# how to twist two wires into a blender?

Tags: modeling

have next problem. One wire is twisting around second, but second is not do same
[image: problem]

i want create next:[image: i want do this]

Comment: i use "Screw" modifire for 2 circles

Comment: Hello, have you tried moving the circle that doesn't get "screwed" along the X or Y axis ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment by Giorgious echo: the circle that is not getting screwed is perfectly centered on the object origin. Move the geometry to that the touching point of the two circles is what is over the origin.